# Through shell, adding an user with a slash path ("/") as directory : ssh/sftp impossible, even after re-creation of it with a named directory

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, sftp

First, what I'm trying to do is to jail (chroot) the user in a specfic directory for sftp access. I found a great tutorial that made the job, you can find it here : http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/. You should read it first (it's very short) to understand the rest.

With the example in the link, I've no problem to create **sftpusers** group, **guestuser** user and lock it to the */sftp/guestuser/incoming* directory. Here is how it's done :

```
groupadd sftpusers
useradd -g sftpusers -d /incoming -s /sbin/nologin guestuser
passwd guestuser
chown guestuser:sftpusers /sftp/guestuser/incoming
service ssh restart
```

What I've tried to do after is to lock another user (we call it "test") from the same group in */sftp/test*. So I've created user like this :

```
useradd -g sftpusers -d / -s /sbin/nologin test
```

You see, instead */incoming* as directory, I've just put "/", then I've changed rights to */sftp/test* and restart ssh. But connection fails and give me this error : **Write failed: Broken pipe**

I thought it was due to the wrong path "/", so I decided to delete user and re-create it with an */incoming* directory :

```
userdel test
useradd -g sftpusers -d /incoming -s /sbin/nologin test
passwd test
chown test:sftpusers /sftp/test/incoming
service ssh restart
```

But even after, the **test** user seems to be compromise for ever, because I have the same error when I try to connect through sftp : **Write failed: Broken pipe Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer**

EDIT :

Here is the log file for sshd :

```
Jan 24 12:46:20 ns sshd[13786]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Jan 24 12:46:23 ns sshd[13786]: Accepted password for test from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 37838 ssh2
Jan 24 12:46:23 ns sshd[13786]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user test by (uid=0)
Jan 24 12:46:24 ns sshd[13949]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/sftp/test"
Jan 24 12:46:24 ns sshd[13786]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user test
Jan 24 12:48:17 ns sshd[14103]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Jan 24 12:48:19 ns sshd[14103]: Invalid user brad from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Jan 24 12:48:19 ns sshd[14103]: input_userauth_request: invalid user brad [preauth]
Jan 24 12:48:19 ns sshd[14103]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Jan 24 12:48:19 ns sshd[14103]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Jan 24 12:48:22 ns sshd[14103]: Failed password for invalid user brad from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 42756 ssh2
Jan 24 12:48:22 ns sshd[14103]: Received disconnect from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the debug log for `sshd`.  You'll likely find it complain about the home directory for user `test` not being secure.

The `sshd` is very strict about access to the user's credentials in `$HOME/.ssh` and will disconnect when it cannot access the directory, or when it detects permissions that would allow any other account to access it.

```
sshd[13949]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/sftp/test"
```

Make sure that the owner of the directory is the *only* account that can modify any file in $HOME and below.  Pay attention specifically to the group settings

Comment: Ok, but when I delete user test and recreate it with /incoming directory it should work, but it's not. Do you know why ? And could you tell me where to find sshd debug log ? Thanks !

Comment: Even if I change rights (chmod/chown) of a user/group or if I delete group/user and recreate it, it's not working anymore for usernames I used before with "/" as path.